# Bootstrap - displaying categories from database vertically & alphabetically sorted in multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting a list of categories, which varies by page. One page may have only 2, the other may have 15 or 20.

Right now I am displaying them like this:

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-xs-4">Airbags</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">Beanbags</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">Cats</div>

<div class="col-xs-4">Dogs</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">Eagles</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">Frogs</div>

<div class="col-xs-4">Hair Clips</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">Jamaica</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">Microphones</div>

</div>
```

It's a bit hard to read, though ...since it will be displayed like:

```
Airbags       Beanbags   Cats
Dogs          Eagles     Frogs
Hair Clips    Jamaica    Microphones
```

What I'd like to do is display them `vertically sorted`, so that it's like:

```
Airbags    Dogs     Hair Clips
Beanbags   Eagles   Jamaica
Cats       Frogs    Microphones
```

The way I print the data right now is like this:

```
$output .= '<div class="row">';

array_multisort($names_array, SORT_ASC, $cat_array);

foreach ((array) $cat_array as $row) {
   $output .= '<div class="col-xs-3">
               <a href="' . $row['subcat_link'] . '" class="">' . 
               $row['name'] . '</a></div>';
}

$output .= '</div>';
```

Is there any easy way I'm not aware to achieve the order I want? However only if there are 4 or more categories, I think ...because otherwise it would be impossible to get them underneath each other with columns.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into using `array_chunk` - you split your array into 3 arrays, and then show the `$i`th item from each:

```
$cat_array = array_chunk((array)$cat_array, 3);
foreach($cat_array as $column) {
    $output .= '<div class="col-xs-3">';
    foreach ($column as $row) {
       $output .= '<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><a href="' . 
                  $row['subcat_link'] . '" class="">' . $row['name'] . '</a></div></div>';
    }
    $output .= '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm trying to get that working. Trying to figure out what to do if there are 20 categories for example as it would mess up after 6 rows.

Comment: I think I'm figuring it out, by increasing the `3` to something higher :)

Answer (score 0):

How i did it in bootstrap 4.5 and i am using laravel 7 php framework

```
<div class="row">
     @foreach ($sortedServices->chunk(ceil(count($sortedServices) / 3)) as $chunkService)
          <div class="col-sm-4 text-left">
               @foreach ($chunkService as $service)
                    <div class="row col">
                         <a href="#">{{ ucwords($service->name) }}</a>
                    </div>
               @endforeach
          </div>
     @endforeach
 </div>
```

$sortedServices variable is alphabetic order list